# How to map the electrostatic potential from GAUSSIAN, on a solvent accessible surface?

Tags: software, gaussian, visualization-software, electrostatic, implicit-solvent

Gaussian cubegen and surface generators in Gaussview seem to only allow to map the ESP on SCF densities. I used G16 for the ESP generation. I would like to plot it on the solvent accessible surface. Is there any (free) software that allows me to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Jmol](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/) software is able to plot different [surfaces](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/docs/surface/).

In the example below, the system is a Mobius strip and the ESP was calculated using [MOPAC](http://openmopac.net/) but as Jmol is full compatible with Gaussian outputs, I think there will be no problem.

Mobius strip structure:

[image]

Mobius solvent-accessible surface (SAS):

[image]

Mobius electrostatic potential mapped on solvent-accessible surface:

[image]

To obtain the images above, the procedure was:

- load the output file from MOPAC with the graphical information.
- open the script console.
- create the SAS with the command: `isosurface ignore(solvent) sasurface 1.2`
- map the electrostatic potential on SAS with the command:  `isosurface resolution 6 sasurface map mep`